# Не определяется SD карта: usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62

Tags: linux, ssd, sd

В интернете http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-898939.html пишут, что нужно сделать

```
 rmmod ehci_hcd
```

сделал

```
root@mh:/home/xuser# rmmod ehci_hcd
rmmod: ERROR: Module ehci_hcd is builtin.
root@mh:/home/xuser#
```

Что за флешнакопитель? Это SD-карта. подключал через переходник, думал переходник неисправен. Подключил через цифрорвой фотоаппарат - то же самое.
Переходник   проверил картой с цифр.фот - переходник рабочий.

При подключении карты через фотик или переходник, она не определяется (или почти определяется). Индикатор мигает и мигает..., но в лог попадет что флешка обнаружена. А потом все пропадает :(  Думаю скачать freebsd, (я сейчас на Линуксах) и в ней попробовать подключить эту флешку. Что еще можно сделать?

```
[93668.296028] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93668.476036] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93668.984804] usb 2-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[93669.002809] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=8168
[93669.002821] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[93669.002828] usb 2-2: Product: USB Mass Storage Device
[93669.002833] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: USB Reader  
[93669.002838] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 816820090724
[93669.005910] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[93669.006135] scsi host192: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[93670.012880] scsi 192:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB Mass  Storage Device       PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[93670.016362] sd 192:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[93670.200046] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93670.600053] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93670.780033] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93671.280038] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93671.684050] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93671.864040] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93672.364065] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93672.764034] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93672.944068] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93673.444069] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93673.844042] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93674.024031] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93674.528041] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93674.928056] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93675.332048] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93675.736045] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93675.916037] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93676.416051] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93676.816038] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93676.996036] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93677.500050] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93677.900050] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93678.080035] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93678.584031] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93678.984063] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93679.164035] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93679.664034] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93680.064033] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93680.672036] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93681.068054] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93681.248034] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93681.752033] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93682.152044] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93682.332045] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93682.642855] sd 192:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[93682.642864] sd 192:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[93682.649820] sd 192:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[93682.649828] sd 192:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[93682.656806] sd 192:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[93682.656818] sd 192:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[93682.844062] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93683.248033] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93683.644043] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93684.048061] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93684.228045] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93684.728037] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93685.132050] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93685.524058] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93685.924038] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93686.320042] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93686.716062] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93686.896062] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93687.396054] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93687.800043] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93687.980036] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93688.480040] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93688.880034] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93689.060031] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93689.564050] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93689.968049] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93690.368058] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93690.776038] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93690.956034] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93691.452075] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93691.852048] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93692.248032] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 26 using ohci-pci
[93692.454801] usb 2-2: device firmware changed
[93692.454878] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 26
[93692.460133] sd 192:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[93692.460142] sd 192:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[93692.460174] sd 192:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[93692.680045] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93692.860047] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93693.368805] usb 2-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[93693.386799] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=8168
[93693.386806] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[93693.386812] usb 2-2: Product: USB Mass Storage Device
[93693.386818] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: USB Reader  
[93693.386823] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 816820090724
[93693.389920] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[93693.390143] scsi host193: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[93694.396833] scsi 193:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB Mass  Storage Device       PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[93694.397235] sd 193:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[93694.580062] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93694.984031] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93695.380053] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93695.784044] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93696.180044] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93696.588065] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93696.768036] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93697.268057] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93697.668037] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93697.848035] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93698.352038] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93698.748036] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93699.152056] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93699.552039] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93699.956051] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93700.360050] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93700.756032] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93700.936030] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93701.440040] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93701.844048] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93702.244035] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93702.645023] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93703.044034] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93703.452035] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93703.632047] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93704.136055] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93704.540055] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93704.940045] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93705.146847] sd 193:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[93705.146856] sd 193:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[93705.344058] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93705.525257] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93705.845830] sd 193:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[93705.845840] sd 193:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[93705.852809] sd 193:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[93705.852815] sd 193:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[93706.036043] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93706.440061] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93706.620037] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93707.120050] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93707.520057] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93707.700031] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93708.200031] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93708.588033] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93708.768036] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93709.264046] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93709.664037] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93709.844057] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93710.344043] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93710.752040] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93710.932031] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93711.432036] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 27 using ohci-pci
[93711.638810] usb 2-2: can't restore configuration #1 (error=-62)
[93711.638902] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 27
[93711.644272] sd 193:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[93711.644285] sd 193:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[93711.644338] sd 193:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[93711.836034] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 28 using ohci-pci
[93712.016050] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93712.320795] usb 2-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[93712.356796] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=8168
[93712.356803] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[93712.356806] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: USB Reader  
[93712.356809] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 816820090724
[93712.359852] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[93712.359984] scsi host194: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[93713.368875] scsi 194:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB Mass  Storage Device       PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[93713.371599] sd 194:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[93713.552035] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 28 using ohci-pci
[93713.758799] usb 2-2: can't restore configuration #1 (error=-62)
[93713.758893] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 28
[93713.764215] sd 194:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[93713.764224] sd 194:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[93713.764258] sd 194:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[93713.764266] sd 194:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[93713.764291] sd 194:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[93713.764297] sd 194:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[93713.764583] sd 194:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[93713.960058] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 29 using ohci-pci
[93714.364812] usb 2-2: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[93714.382807] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=8168
[93714.382818] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[93714.382824] usb 2-2: Product: USB Mass Storage Device
[93714.382829] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: USB Reader  
[93714.382834] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 816820090724
[93714.385910] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[93714.386176] scsi host195: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[93715.392830] scsi 195:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB Mass  Storage Device       PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[93715.393201] sd 195:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[93715.580037] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 29 using ohci-pci
[93715.984033] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 29 using ohci-pci
[93716.384058] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 29 using ohci-pci
[93716.796036] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 29 using ohci-pci
[93716.976052] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93717.476068] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 29 using ohci-pci
[93717.884055] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 29 using ohci-pci
[93718.064065] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93718.564043] usb 2-2: reset full-speed USB device number 29 using ohci-pci
[93718.770798] usb 2-2: can't restore configuration #1 (error=-62)
[93718.770861] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 29
[93718.776769] sd 195:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[93718.776778] sd 195:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[93718.776796] sd 195:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[93718.776801] sd 195:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[93718.776817] sd 195:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[93718.776821] sd 195:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[93718.777089] sd 195:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[93718.777093] sd 195:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[93718.777119] sd 195:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[93718.968067] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 30 using ohci-pci
[93719.148037] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -62
[93719.479797] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=8168
[93719.479804] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[93719.479808] usb 2-2: Product: USB Mass Storage Device
[93719.479811] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: USB Reader  
[93719.479813] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 816820090724
[93719.482793] usb 2-2: can't set config #1, error -62
root@mh:/home/xuser#
```

без sd-карты

```
root@mh:/home/xuser# lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro 
Bus 002 Device 044: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
root@mh:/home/xuser# lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  55,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   1,9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda2   8:2    0    54G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 232,9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 232,9G  0 part /media/xuser/9bd1fae0-bcb9-4677-9f1a-28ac7079dccc
root@mh:/home/xuser#
```

с sd-картой

```
root@mh:/home/xuser# lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro 
Bus 002 Device 044: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 101: ID 14cd:8168 Super Top 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
root@mh:/home/xuser# lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  55,9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   1,9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda2   8:2    0    54G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 232,9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 232,9G  0 part /media/xuser/9bd1fae0-bcb9-4677-9f1a-28ac7079dccc
root@mh:/home/xuser#
```

Answer (score 1):

**error -62** это таймаут операции, то есть возможно флешка просто нерабочая, надо понять работает ли она в том же фотике, хотя возможно ошибка в драйвере USB. можно проверить использовав Live диск с другой системой

Comment: нет. в фотоаппарате не работает. Мне притащили  ее потому что она не подает никаких признаков жизни в винде. Значит все пропало. Смысле фряку качать нет никакого. Почему я думал что Фря может помогла бы? Есть такое видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Wu4katF1U8 и https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ks0J8pLfBf0 могу со своей спасательной флешки загрузиться и там подтыкнуть карту, только смысл какой?

Comment: думаю что она дохлая, видимо сдох контроллер, тут только чинить в случае если её можно разобрать, ибо если это MicroSD то там должно быть что то ну очень ценное чтобы её восстанавливать

Comment: ну разбирать ее только под микроскопом нужно.  Вообщем-то "все пропало" :( Если бы она определялась то проблем бы не было. я знаком с foremost photorec testdisk.

Comment: А если в серьезный сервисный центр обратиться, то какие шансы?

Comment: Если не SD полноразмерная то с прямыми руками можно и самому, но стрёмно, ибо надо выпаять чип памяти и впаять его в аналогичную карту, если MicroSD то ценник восстановления будет совсем не гуманный.